# Help me understand why fixed point iteration works for backwards Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, eulers-method

Euler's method for integration can be written as,

$$
f(x) = x + g(x)
$$

Assuming that $g$ has a Lipschitz constant which is $<1$, it is a contraction mapping and therefore has a fixed point by the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). If we run the equation in reverse given the endpoint, we can use fixed point iteration to arrive at the correct starting point for each time step given $y = f(x)$ and an initial guess for $x_0 = x^*$ which could be anywhere

$$
x_{[i+1]} = y - g(x_{[i]})
$$

Which basically gives us $f^{-1}(y) = x$ at convergence. I understand why $f^{-1}$ has a fixed point, but I cannot understand why that fixed point is going to just happen to be the specific and correct point we are looking for....$x$.

Is there any easy way to see why this is true?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Which mapping you are writing about? About $f$, which isn't a self map? About $x\mapsto x+hf(t,x)$? If so then what is $t$? Fixed points of what map are you interested in?

Comment: I updated the question to remove $t$ and hopefully be more understandable. Is it clear now?

Comment: Your abstract fixed-point equation is not related to the Euler method. The method is $x_n=x_{n-1}+hf(t_n,x_n)$, thus $x=y+g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

First correct the fixed-point equation to $x=y+g(x)$ with $y=x_{n-1}$, $g(x)=hf(t_n,x)$ for an ODE $\dot x=f(t,x)$, and the resulting fixed point $x_n=x^*$ is expected to be $O(h)$ close to $y$.

For $h$ sufficiently small you have both a small enough Lipschitz constant for $g$ and can take the previous value $y$ on the numerical trajectory as initial value for the fixed-point iteration, as it will be inside the basin of attraction.

Using the forward Euler value $x=x_{n-1}+hf(t_{n-1},x_{n-1})$ as predictor results in a faster convergence for step sizes that produce a good accuracy. For stiff ODE with large step sizes a sizeable disconnect between forward and backward Euler is expected.

You are correct in your doubt, for stiff ODE and large step sizes, you can have that either the iteration does not converge, or that it jumps to a fixed point that is not close to the trajectory.

Comment: I don't see why having the values in the basin of attraction explains why the fixed point should be the point we are looking for. I think I am missing something simple

Comment: Having a Lipschitz constant $q=Lh<1$ for the iteration means that during the iteration the distance to the fixed point reduces by the $q$ in each step. This of course also assumes that the iteration starts and remains in the region where this Lipschitz constant is valid.

Comment: In particular the Banach fixed point theorem is what guarantees that the fixed point is unique within this region.

Comment: Right, but I still don't see why that point must be $y_n$.

Comment: You should probably update your question so that all iterations are in forward time. Then you should get the formula of the implicit Euler method that can then be compared to the explicit Euler method. // Because locally the fixed point is unique, or because all other fixed points have a distance of $\sim h^{-1}$ from the initial guess.

Answer (score 1):

In backward Euler run forward in time you want $y_{n+1}=y_n+h f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ to happen. This is a fixed point equation $y_{n+1}=g_n(y_{n+1})$ where $g_n(y)=y_n+h f(t_n,y)$.

Replacing $y_{n+1}$ by $y_{n+1}^{(i+1)}$ on the left and $y_{n+1}^{(i)}$ on the right gives a fixed point iteration which if it converges gives a solution to the original fixed point equation. The iteration converges if $g_n$ is contractive, which happens if the iteration remains in a region where $f(t_n,\cdot)$ is $L$-Lipschitz for some $L<h^{-1}$.

As $h \to 0$, there will become only one solution to $y=y_n+h g_n(y)$ which is within $O(h)$ of $y_n$, and this is the fixed point you are looking for. If $h$ is too large then you may indeed find that the iteration converges to a different fixed point entirely. This is a somewhat unsatisfying answer since it relies on the notion of doing backward Euler (or whatever other implicit method) with multiple step sizes to validate that $\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{h}$ is not too big (because $O(h)$ is an asymptotic concept, so it says nothing about the size of the prefactor). Sadly I don't think that you can do much better with this part of the analysis.

Comment: I changed the notation in my question based on the comment by @Mateo . The part which I cannot see is 'why' the contraction point happens to be $x$ (based on new notation) and not some other random point in the region. Everyone seems to take this for granted, and maybe I am overlooking something really obvious, but I don't see any obvious reason why $x$ must be the fixed point.